# DataGridView Not Showing Up

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to show a query with my results in a  datagridview. My connection works, i just can't seem to get the results to show.I'm throwing an error that says I havent initialized the ExecuteReader:Connection property  here is my code 
My question is: Am i not initializing the ExecuteReader, correctly? I'm new to vb and I'm trying to understand what i'm doing wrong here.

```
Public Sub Form1_Load(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    connection string = "Data Source" ' I'm not including my data source for the question 
    SqlConnect = New Connection (connectionString)

    SqlConnect.Open()

    strQuery = "Select Book Number"
       "FROM Books"
       "Where ID Code"
    SqlQuery.CommandText = strQuery
    SqlDataReader = SQLQuery.ExecuteReader()
    SqlDataReader.Read()
    SqlQuery.Connection = SqlConnect
    SQLQuery.CommandText = strQuery


    SQlConnect. Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you parsed the Docs about the use of the Connection, Command and related objects? See the simple example in [SqlConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection) and take a look at the other examples there. You can find many. Note also the `Using` statement, where the Connection object is declared. Take a look at that, too.

Comment: Is Book the name of one field in the database and Number the name of another? Or is it just one field named "Book Number"?

Comment: `Where ID Code` makes no sense. The Where clause will limit the records returned by some criteria. Example `Where IDCode = 7`. Again, the name of a data field would not normally contain a space.

Comment: You cannot concatenate strings the way you have tried here in your Select statement. Get rid of all the double quotes except the beginning and ending double quotes.

Comment: Can you provide the column names and datatypes of the fields in your database?

Answer (score 0):

To address the specific issue, you're getting an error message that you haven't set the `Connection` property.  Here's your code:

```
SqlDataReader = SQLQuery.ExecuteReader()
SqlDataReader.Read()
SqlQuery.Connection = SqlConnect
```

Would you expect to be able to walk through a door and then open it afterwards?  I would hope not.  So why would you expect to be able to execute a command against a database and then tell it what database connection to use after doing so?

Apart from that, there's nothing in that code related to a `DataGridView`, so this question has nothing to do with that.  Research should show that the usual way to display data in a `DataGridView` is to populate a `DataTable` and then bind it to the grid.  You need to look into how to populate a `DataTable`.  You can do that with a data reader but you certainly won't be calling read and, if you want to edit and save the data, you should be using a data adapter instead.

Answer (score 0):

put your `SqlDataReader = SQLQuery.ExecuteReader()` and `SqlDataReader.Read()` under `SqlQuery.Connection = SqlConnect`

You should specify the connection first before execuitng your`Reader`